# How to get next index value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the next index value in each loop, if index is last(here it is 2), take first index value.

So I tried the following code but not working.

```
keyword = 'on';
var nextitem = '';
$(".clsiteration").each(function(index, el) {
    if ($(this).attr("src").toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) > 0) {
        if (index == 2)
            nextitem = $(this).first().attr('data-val');
        else
            nextitem = $(this).next().attr('data-val');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
        <img src="img_off.jpg" class="clsiteration" data-val="k1" >
        <img src="img_on.jpg" class="clsiteration" data-val="k2" >
        <img src="img_off.jpg" class="clsiteration" data-val="k3" >
</div>
```

How can I get next index value ? Thanks

Comment: $(this).next().index() https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet if you look at else part it is there lol :)

Comment: @guradio No, I don't see it..

Comment: You might want the check to be `>= 0` or `> -1`, note. `0` means the substring was found at the start of the string.

Comment: What type of element is `.clsiteration`? The only element I can think of that's valid to have `src` and `value` attributes is an `input type="image"` and they are very outdated. Could you add a sample of your HTML to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `Snippet` it is how `next()` works in `JQUERY`.

```js
$(function(){
keyword = 'k1';
var nextitem = '';
$(".clsiteration").each(function(index, el) {
        if (index === 2){
            nextitem = $(this).closest("div").find("img:eq(0)").data('val');
          }
        else {
            nextitem = $(this).next().data('val');
          }
  console.log(nextitem);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <img src="img_off.jpg" class="clsiteration" data-val="k1" >
        <img src="img_on.jpg" class="clsiteration" data-val="k2" >
        <img src="img_off.jpg" class="clsiteration" data-val="k3" >
</div>
```